# how can i call mutiple files(bash files) from subprocess.call in python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

#i am trying to run all the bash scripts in plugin folder

```
import sys,os,subprocess
    folder_path=os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'plugins'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'plugins'))

    for file in folder_path:
        if file == '~':
           continue

        elif file.split('.')[1]=="sh":
          print file
         subprocess.call(['./plugins/${file} what'],shell=True,executable='/bin/bash')

    it shows error:
    bash: /bin/bash: ./plugins/: Is a directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to actually insert the `file` variable into the subprocess call string:

```
subprocess.call(['./plugins/%s what' % file],shell=True,executable='/bin/bash')
```